# Timeout on custom membership provider in asp.net 4.0

Tags: asp.net-membership

I have implemented custom membership provider in my project.  i kept one flag on database to get the users online. i want to reset this flag on the log out, i can do this if the user log out properly . I have to reset the flag on database even if the the browser closed directly or on any machine failure or normal time out, any tricks on membership provider to solve this.  experts am waiting for your answers!!!!!!!

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

just put a field for users like IS_LOGOUT_BUTTON_PRESSED typeof(bool) default false
if the user click LogOut set it TRUE.
if the user closes browser, it will stay false. Then you can see what user did.

Comment: thanks,
how this variable helps to know the user session is available or expired.

Answer (score 0):

I am afraid that you are tilting against windmills.

You will notice that the sql providers implement the 'users online' by simply updating last activity in most all provider methods (and subsequently the stored procedures) and then using a predefined 'online time window' to determine if the user *may* still be online.

To implement an authoritative 'is_online' flag would require that you have complete control over the user's means of starting a session and ending a session, which you do not and can not do due to both the nature of the browser ui and the way that sessions and ticket expirations are bumped.

So you can never *really* be sure whether a user is online or not, rendering any efforts you have made to track this metric unreliable.

And unreliable data is often of less value than no data at all.

I am quite certain that you will find nothing but frustration in attempting to apply an absolute, as described in your question, to the stateless and freeform nature of sessions and tickets.

Sorry I have not better news.